# What does 'border rat' mean?

Tags: meaning

I've heard it in a documentary. So, a guy "works" for a drug cartel and he doesn't have a good position yet. He's a border rat. What does it mean? That he's a courier who transports drugs across the border? Or that he explores the border to find "weaker" areas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A 'border rat' is someone who hops back and forth over national borders illegally, particularly between the USA and Mexico.

Here's a couple of references: [1](https://gringarusamexicana.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/old-and-new-border-rats/), [2](https://travelerstales.com/a-border-rat-in-the-twilight-zone/)

Comment: I think it's important to note that it is sometimes derogatory slang. Calling someone a *something* rat can imply they are an unwanted pest. For example, skate rats, surf rats, mall rats, etc. Often the "rats" are a [subculture](https://sociologydictionary.org/subculture/) and don't see being identified as part of that subculture as a bad thing, but often people outside the subculture do perceive it negatively.